# Loading a custom json file - highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have a problem with loading the .json file:

```
[
    [
        [
            "2014-11-19 06:00:00",
            "1.1"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-19 14:00:00",
            "4.9"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-19 15:00:00",
            "4.9"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-19 16:00:00",
            "4.9"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-19 17:00:00",
            "4.9"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-19 18:00:00",
            "4.9"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "2014-11-13 23:00:00",
            "194"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-14 00:00:00",
            "195"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-14 01:00:00",
            "187"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-14 02:00:00",
            "191"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-14 03:00:00",
            "218"
        ],
        [
            "2014-11-14 04:00:00",
            "170"
        ]
    ]
]
```

values:

```
[[data, valueTemperature],[data,WindMax]]
```

I tried in this way, but does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Temperatura'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: '5 dni'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',

    },


    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },

        min: -25,
        max: 25,
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Prędkość wiatru',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} m/s',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 15,
        opposite: true
    }],

    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },

    series: [{}]
};

var chart;

$.getJSON('test.json', function (data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


});

});
```

How to correctly write it for a data type?

Comment: Are you hosting the files with a web server of any kind? Errors in console?

Comment: Yes ,  loads the file from my server, so no problem with ACCES-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGN. No errors in the console. The file date is correctly captured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. You've stored numeric data as strings. While trying to find a solution, I had to strip the `"`'s off the temperature and wind speed values or I'd get [Highcharts Error #14](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14)
2. You have two data series, yet you are only creating one object in `options.series`. You should be creating two series objects and adding them to the `options.series` array.
3. For the second series, you must specify which y axis to use. In this case `yAxis == 1`.
4. The max value for your second y axis is too low to display the data.

Here's an example to showcase the above: http://jsfiddle.net/6yvdkp20/1/

```
$(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperatura'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '5 dni'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },
        yAxis: [
            { // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}°C',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                    }
                },

                min: -25,
                max: 25,
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'Prędkość wiatru',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{value} m/s',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                    }
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 200,
                opposite: true
            }
        ],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        series: [
            {
                data: [
                    [
                        "2014-11-19 06:00:00",
                        1.1
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-19 14:00:00",
                        4.9
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-19 15:00:00",
                        4.9
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-19 16:00:00",
                        4.9
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-19 17:00:00",
                        4.9
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-19 18:00:00",
                        4.9
                    ]
                ]
            },{
                yAxis: 1, // This means the second yAxis will be used to plot this series
                data:[
                    [
                        "2014-11-13 23:00:00",
                        194
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-14 00:00:00",
                        195
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-14 01:00:00",
                        187
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-14 02:00:00",
                        191
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-14 03:00:00",
                        218
                    ],
                    [
                        "2014-11-14 04:00:00",
                        170
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    $('#container').highcharts(options);
});
```

Since you mentioned in the comments that you cannot change the format of the data you are fetching, you will need to correct the format after receiving the data. The following function *should* correctly do that (though I make no guarantees):

```
function fixFormat(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < dataSeries[0].length; ++i) {
        dataSeries[0][i][1] = parseFloat(dataSeries[0][i][1]);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < dataSeries[1].length; ++i) {
        dataSeries[1][i][1] = parseInt(dataSeries[1][i][1]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$.getJSON('http://kamery.topr.pl/meteo/charts/moko.php', function (data) {
    // Correct the formatting
    fixFormat(data);

    // Put the data in the right place
    options.series[0].data = data[0];
    options.series[1].data = data[1];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, further file will not load properly.
Below the code json:
http://pastebin.com/swTRGNgX

The code:`
series: [
             {
                 data: []
                 
             }, {
                 yAxis: 1, // This means the second yAxis will be used to plot this series
                 data: []
             }
        ]
    };

   

    $.getJSON('test/test.json', function (data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        options.series[1].data = data;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });`

Comment: You've set both `options.series[0]` and `options.series[1]` to `data`. You should set the first to `data[0]` and the second to `data[1]`.

Comment: @Sebastiano In addition to my comment above, the page you are fetching the JSON data from still stores the numeric values as strings (see issue 1 I mentioned above). You will need to correct all the issues above before your code will work.

Comment: No I do not understand how to improve the numeric data as strings. I do not have opportunities to improve the json file

Comment: @Sebastiano I've edited my answer with two new blocks of code to solve the formatting issue. I hope that helps.

Comment: Works. I have a question : How to delete a part of the date on xAxis ( 2014-11-15 9:00:00 p.m. so ) and I would like this: 11-15 21:00 ?

Comment: @Sebastiano Excellent :) Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted. You should take a look at the [documentation for highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis). That link points specifically to the yAxis documentation. You'll see an entry for date formatting options (`dateTimeLabelFormats: Object`) with a jsfiddle example.

In future, you should search the documentation thoroughly. I resolved all the above issues by taking a look at the example code given by the highcharts documentation.